# Chai assertion is passing even thought it should fail

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, tdd, chai

I am fetching the array of objects "subscriptions" which should return me array with 3 subscriptions in it. But when I try to fail the test by asserting it with length 2, it passes. Is something wrong with my approach?

Thankyou in advance :)

```
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');

chai.use(chaiAsPromised);

const assert = chai.assert;
const expect = chai.expect;
```

```
    it('trying to get subscriptions with token', async () => {
        try {
            const { data } = await axios.get('/subscriptions', config);
            console.log(data); // returns array of objects
            console.log(data.length); // length is 3
            assert.strictEqual(data.length, 2);
        } catch (error) {

        }
    });
```

I tried using expect but as I am new to the TDD I don't have my head wrapped around it that much.

Comment: I'm not sure it it's it, but you are catching error from `assert.strictEqual(data.length, 2);`. Try removing the `try...catch`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.